# Form collective access current ID as a name

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

```
@foreach($cities as $idx => $city)
{{ Form::select('city['.$id.'], $list_cities, !empty($cities['cities_id'][$city->pivot->id : null, ['id' => 'zone_id', 'class' => 'form-control mav-select', 'placeholder' => 'Select Zone', 'disabled' => !$SaveButton]) }}
```

I have this code in my Blade, I am trying to access $list_cities ID that was selected to pass the selected city id. As of now, I am selecting city['id'] that is coming from $cities array, but I am confused about how to achieve this with Form Collective as I am completely new to this library and to Laravel.

Comment: add name attributes

Comment: @KamleshPaul list_cities has 97 => string '1 - New York' 
      98 => string '2 - Los Angeles' 
      99 => string '3 - Hong Kong'

Answer (score 0):

modify 
`'name'=>'city'` added

```php
@foreach($cities as $idx => $city)
{{ Form::select('city['.$id.'], $list_cities, !empty($cities['cities_id'][$city->pivot->id : null, ['id' => 'zone_id', 'class' => 'form-control mav-select', 'placeholder' => 'Select Zone','name'=>'city', 'disabled' => !$SaveButton]) }}
```